Localization with expression-based bindings
I'm following Gerald Versluis tutorial on Localization in .NET MAUI. He use the following extension for localizing texts in XAML:
[ContentProperty(nameof(Name))]
public class TranslateExtension : IMarkupExtension<BindingBase> {
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public BindingBase ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) {
        return new Binding {
            Mode = BindingMode.OneWay,
            Path = $"[{Name}]",
            Source = LocalizationResourceManager.Instance
        };
    }

    object IMarkupExtension.ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) {
        return ProvideValue(serviceProvider);
    }
}

But this gives the warning:

IL2026: Using member 'Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Binding.Binding()' which has 'RequiresUnreferencedCodeAttribute' can break functionality when trimming application code. Using bindings with string paths is not trim safe. Use expression-based binding instead.

How can I convert the binding in the code above to an expression-based binding?
I tried using BindingBase.Create:
return BindingBase.Create<LocalizationResourceManager, string> (
    lm => lm[Name], 
    BindingMode.OneWay, 
    source: LocalizationResourceManager.Instance);     

But I then get a compile error saying "The lambda must be static".

The alternative is "compiled bindings". Put the "magic" in the bound property getter. e.g. Text="{Binding Name}" .... public string Name => Magic( nameof( this.Name) );

Thanks @GerrySchmitz, but I don't understand how to implement your suggestion. Could you provide a more verbose example code?

(Property) public string NameLabel => SomethingThatReturnsALocalNameLabel( "some key" ); ... is an example of an "expression" that will not cause "trimming" issues. Where the XAML is bound to "NameLabel" (via some control). Where "property" is defined, I have no idea: "code behind"; "view model"; model interface; whatever. The solution lies in the "getter" of the property that is displayed in the UI. In one case (AOE), every piece of text has a id number that is used across multiple language resources. The "getter" would be a "resource lookup" using the id key.

All the number "keys" have an "English" alias used in the code. (For English language developers). The "alias" is very expressive in terms of what the "text" says; e.g. WhatEnemySaysWhenInYourBase.

[EDIT]
I think you're very close. You need to mark your expression with the static keyword. I believe the syntax you're looking for is:
return BindingBase.Create<LocalizationResourceManager, string> (
    static lm => lm[Name], 
    BindingMode.OneWay, 
    source: LocalizationResourceManager.Instance);  

To reproduce the trimming problem, I temporarily added the following lines to Gerald Versluis's tutorial project:
<PropertyGroup>
    <IsTrimmable>true</IsTrimmable>
    <WarningsAsErrors>IL2026</WarningsAsErrors>
</PropertyGroup>

I also reviewed the GitHub repo containing the tutorial and have the following recommended improvements to TranslateExtension

Make Name a BindableProperty so it can come from your view model
Add a TranslatedName property so that the markup extension can react to changes to the rebuilt string
Optional (bonus) add X0 and X1 so that we can have string resources with 0, 1, or 2 parameters

[ContentProperty(nameof(Name))]
public class TranslateExtension : BindableObject, IMarkupExtension<BindingBase> {
    public static BindableProperty NameProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Name), typeof(string), typeof(TranslateExtension), null,
            propertyChanged: (b, o, n) => ((TranslateExtension)b).OnTranslatedNameChanged());
    public string Name
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(NameProperty);
        set => SetValue(NameProperty, value);
    }

    public static BindableProperty X0Property = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(X0), typeof(object), typeof(TranslateExtension), null,
            propertyChanged: (b, o, n) => ((TranslateExtension)b).OnTranslatedNameChanged());
    public object X0
    {
        get => GetValue(X0Property);
        set => SetValue(X0Property, value);
    }

    public static BindableProperty X1Property = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(X1), typeof(object), typeof(TranslateExtension), null,
            propertyChanged: (b, o, n) => ((TranslateExtension)b).OnTranslatedNameChanged());
    public object X1
    {
        get => GetValue(X1Property);
        set => SetValue(X1Property, value);
    }

    public string? TranslatedName
        => (Name is string name && LocalizationResourceManager.Instance[name] is string translatedName)
            ? String.Format(translatedName, new object[] { X0, X1 })
            : null;

    public void OnTranslatedNameChanged() => OnPropertyChanged(nameof(TranslatedName));

    public TranslateExtension()
    {
        LocalizationResourceManager.Instance.PropertyChanged += (s, e) => OnTranslatedNameChanged();
    }

    public BindingBase ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        => Binding.Create<TranslateExtension, string?>(
            static source => source.TranslatedName,
            mode: BindingMode.OneWay,
            source: this
        );

    object IMarkupExtension.ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        => ProvideValue(serviceProvider);
}

With these additional changes, the following will be possible:
<Label Text="{local:Translate HelloWorld, X0={Binding User}, X1={Binding Weather}}" />
<!-- HelloWorld can now be a string resource with parameters, e.g. "Hello {0}, today's weather is {1}!" -->
<!-- User and Weather are strings from the view model -->

<!-- By making Translate.Name Bindable I can store translatable strings in the view model. -->
<CollectionView ItemsSources="{Binding Fruits}">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <Label Text="{local:Translate {Binding .}}" />
         </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>

[MORE EDITS]
Here's another version of TranslateExtension that has a different implementation to how it detects and binds to the X0, X1 parameters which doesn't have the BindingContext issues.
[ContentProperty(nameof(Name))]
public class TranslateExtension : IMarkupExtension<BindingBase>, IMultiValueConverter {
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public object X0 { get; set; }

    public object X1 { get; set; }

    public BindingBase ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        => new MultiBinding
        {
            Bindings = new List<BindingBase> {
                BindingBase.Create<TranslateExtension, string?>(static source => source.Name, mode: BindingMode.OneWay, source: this),
                BindingBase.Create<LocalizationResourceManager, CultureInfo>(static lm => lm.Culture, mode: BindingMode.OneWay, source: LocalizationResourceManager.Instance),
                X0 is BindingBase x0Binding ? x0Binding : BindingBase.Create<object?, object?>(static obj  => obj, mode: BindingMode.OneWay, source: X0),
                X1 is BindingBase x1Binding ? x1Binding : BindingBase.Create<object?, object?>(static obj  => obj, mode: BindingMode.OneWay, source: X1),
            },
            Converter = this
        };

    object IMarkupExtension.ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        => ProvideValue(serviceProvider);

    public object? Convert(object?[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        => (values.Length > 1 && values[0] is string name && LocalizationResourceManager.Instance[name] is string translatedName)
        ? string.Format(translatedName, values.Skip(2).ToArray())
        : null;
    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        => throw new NotImplementedException();
}

References:

See my fork: https://github.com/stephenquan/MauiLocalizationSample/tree/main
See my pull request: https://github.com/jfversluis/MauiLocalizationSample/pull/1


Your suggested improvements are great, but I still get the warning about string bindings not being trim safe. I worry that I will get problems when publishing.

Thanks @torof, based on your feedback, I research further into IL2026 and have updated my answer as a result.

Thanks for the update, it solved the trimming warnings! But I didn't figure out how to bind the X0 parameter to my view model. With value_n being translated to "value: {0}", Text="{Binding Value}" works, Text="{local:Translate value_n, X0='42'}" works, but Text="{local:Translate value_n, X0={Binding Value}}" doesn't. The Value getter is never called. Does the Translate internal binding mess up the Value binding some how?

Yeah the Translate binding doesn't have access to the VisualElement tree so you have to either use Binding Source again or set BindingContext on the Translate markup extension

@torof If you like to try, I have just posted an alternate implementation of TranslateExtension that you may find works better with your bindings.
